# liblognorm rule for nginx logs

Tags: parsing, nginx, rsyslog

I am sending logs to elasticsearch via rsyslog. For the parsing of those logs, I am using liblognorm rule.

I want to create fields of nginx logs,

here is a log entry,

```
127.0.0.1 - kibanaadmin [13/Jun/2017:14:18:17 +0530] "GET /ui/favicons/favicon-32x32.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
```

Here is the pattern file,

```
version=2

rule=:%clientip:ipv4% - %user:word% [%timestamp:char-to:]%] %auth:word% "%verb:alpha% %request:word%" %response:number% %bytes:number% "%referrer:word"%" "%agent:char-to:{"extradata":"("}"
```

The reason for parsefailure is I believe due to the date-time format.

Can somebody help in creating a rule for parsing nginx logs ?

Answer (score 2):

For the aforementioned Nginx access log line you need a rule like this:

```
version=2

rule=:%clientip:ipv4%%-:whitespace%-%-:whitespace%%user:word%%-:whitespace%[%timestamp:char-to{"extradata":"]"}%]%-:whitespace%"%verb:word%%-:whitespace%%request:word%%-:whitespace%%protocol:char-to{"extradata":"\""}%"%-:whitespace%%response_code:number{"format":"number"}%%-:whitespace%%bytes:number{"format":"number"}%%-:whitespace%"%referrer:char-to{"extradata":"\""}%"%-:whitespace%"%agent:char-to{"extradata":"\""}%"
```

which produces the following output (pretty printed):

```
{
    "agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/53.0",
    "referrer": "-",
    "bytes": 0,
    "response_code": 304,
    "protocol": "HTTP\/1.1",
    "request": "\/ui\/favicons\/favicon-32x32.png",
    "verb": "GET",
    "timestamp": "13\/Jun\/2017:14:18:17 +0530",
    "user": "kibanaadmin",
    "clientip": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

To test your log file along with a [Liblognorm](http://www.liblognorm.com/files/manual/configuration.html) rule file more easily you can create a `nginx.rule` file for your rules and run the command:

```
 lognormalizer -H -p -r nginx.rule < nginx.log
```

You can find more information about lognormalizer command [here](http://www.liblognorm.com/files/manual/lognormalizer.html).